# Powershell: Replace all occurrences of different substrings starting with same Unicode char (Regex?)

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, ansi-escape

I have a string:

```
[33m[TEST][90m [93ma wonderful testorius line[90m ([37mbite me[90m) which ends here.
```

You are not able to see it (as stackoverflow will remove it when I post it) but there is a special Unicode char before every `[xxm` where `xx` is a variable number and `[` as well as `m` are fixed. You can find the special char here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd

So, it is like this (the special char is displayed here with a $):

```
$[33m[TEST]$[90m $[93ma wonderful testorius line$[90m ($[37mbite me$[90m) which ends here.
```

Now, I want to remove all `$[xxm` substrings in this line as it is only for colored monitor output but should not be saved to a log file.

So the expected outcome should be:

```
[TEST] a wonderful testorius line (bite me) which ends here.
```

I tried to use RegEx but I dont understand it (perhaps it is extra confusing due to the special char and the open bracked) and I am not able to use wildcards in a normal `.Replace ("this","with_that")` operation.

How am I able to accomplish this?

Comment: `.Replace( )` string method doesn't know what regex is, you need to use `-replace` operator or direct call to `[regex]::Replace( )`

Comment: Okay but I cant comprehend RegEx and already tried online generators. Perhaps my test string is too confusing. Which expression should I put in?

Comment: It's unclear how does the text literally looks and what's your expected outcome.

Comment: I have added  both. $ stands for the special char.

Comment: PowerShell 7.2+ now offers a class that has a method that (hopefully) robustly strips ANIS/VT escape sequences from strings; please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this **simple case**, the following **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation** will do, but note that this is *not* sufficient to robustly remove *all* variations of [ANSI / Virtual Terminal escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```bash
# Sample input.
# Note: `e is used as a placeholder for ESC and replaced with actual ESC chars. 
#       ([char] 0x1b)
#       In PowerShell (Core) 7+, "..." strings directly understand `e as ESC.
$formattedStr = '`e[33m[TEST]`e[90m `e[93ma wonderful testorius line`e[90m (`e[37mbite me`e[90m) which ends here.' -replace '`e', [char] 0x1b

# \x1b is a regex escape sequence that expands to an ESC char.
$formattedStr -replace '\x1b\[\d*m'
```

Generally speaking, it's advisable to look for options on programs producing such for-display-formatted strings to make them output plain-text strings instead, so that the need to strip escape sequences after the fact doesn't even arise.

---

***Robust* PowerShell (Core) 7.2+ solution**:

The new [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated) class can store string with ANSI/VT sequences and convert them to plain-text strings on demand by calling `.ToString('PlainText')` on them:

```bash
# PowerShell 7.2+ only

$formattedStr = "`e[33m[TEST]`e[90m `e[93ma wonderful testorius line`e[90m (`e[37mbite me`e[90m) which ends here."

# -> '[TEST] a wonderful testorius line (bite me) which ends here.'
([System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated] $formattedStr).
  ToString('PlainText')
```

Comment: Would you please add this to your PowerShell solution: `$formattedStr -replace "\x1B\[\d+m"` (got it from a friend) as \x1B seems to be the escape char that $([char] 27) refers to and therefore is straighter.

Comment: Good point, @tar, thanks - answer updated. (I was too narrowly focused on PowerShell's _string interpolation_. In a _regex_, `\x1b` can indeed be used to represent ESC, which also allows switching to _single_-quoted strings (`'...'`), whose use is generally preferable when dealing with regexes. Also note that I'm using `\d*` rather than `\d+`, because `<esc>[m` is technically a valid ANSI escape sequence.